# By setting the culture to en-CA (Canada), how do you force the ASP.NET app to use US date/time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, default, culture

Hopefully this is a quick question- I set my app's culture to "en-CA".  I want everything culture specific to be "en-CA", EXCEPT the date format.  I want the date format to be the US version (mm/dd/yy), NOT Canada's version (dd/mm/yy).  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want "en-US" culture then you should create an en-US culture and use that to format the date time.

```
var provider = new CultureInfo ("en-US", false);
var date = new DateTime (2011, 6, 27, 17, 7, 0);
date.ToString ("d", provider);
```

or

```
var provider = new CultureInfo ("en-US", false);
var date = new DateTime (2011, 6, 27, 17, 7, 0);
date.ToString ("MM/dd/yy", provider);
```

This is different to formatting a string as "MM/dd/yy" in the current culture.
If you use the current culture (en-CA) then month names, day names and the date/time separators will still use Canadian formatting.

Whilst specifying your culture explicitly (en-US) will use the correct spellings, and abbreviations for that culture.

Admittedly you won't notice a huge different with this particular format between these 2 cultures, but if you were using a long date format such as "ddd, dd MMM yyyy" and your current culture was "fr-CA" you would get a much more noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
DateTime date;
date.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
```

to force the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the front-end view, then it would be:

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", DateTime.Now)
```